# Laravel ajax response get values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have ajax like this:

```
$(".cq").on("input", function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "create/reefFormAjax",
    type: "POST",
    data: $(this.form).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      callback(data);
    }
  });
});
function callback(response) {
  $(".sum_whl").val(response);
  $(".sum_rtl").val(response);
}
```

So in my controller I have something like this:

```
$test = $request->all();
return json_encode($test);
```

Then I retrieve data back to my view:

```
  {
    "material": "0",
    "mquantity": null,
    "cq": "2",
    "sum_rtl": null,
    "sum_whl": null
  }
```

The question is how I can get each value from response ?

I tried `$(response).find('cq').val()` or `filter` but I an have error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem, i was using return json_encode instead of return response->json($var); So i grab my values!

Answer (score 1):

The result you get is a JSON response

```
  var response = 
  {
    "material": "0",
    "mquantity": null,
    "cq": "2",
    "sum_rtl": null,
    "sum_whl": null
  };
```

If the JSON is in your `response` variable, you can simply access the element like this

`response.material;  // should print 0
 response.cq;        // will print 2`

Comment: Yes, i have response but when i'm trying console.log(response.cq); it's tell me that value = undefined...

Answer (score 0):

When you return a json(or array) from laravel it automatically turn into a js object. so you can access like this:

```
function callback(response) {
  $(".sum_whl").val(response.sum_whl);
  $(".sum_rtl").val(response.sum_rtl);
}
```

Comment: It still return nothing...  I tried like you saying before

Comment: put `console.log(arguments);` inside callback() That will show what exactly is received by the function.

Comment: Arguments ["{"material":"0","mq":"2","cq":"3","sum_rtl":null,"sum_whl":null}", callee: ƒ, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ] it have) but not showing) when using response.cq or response.mq using console.log()  - undefined

Comment: @Moramu looks like you don't return an array. try these two:
1.instead of using this: `response.sum_whl` try this: `response[0].sum_whl`
2.if it is't working  try` console.log(data);` and tell me what you get

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(response.data[0])` or `console.log(reponse.material)` must be work. Because its json object.

Give it a try.

```
$("#div).html(response.data[0])

$("#div).html(response.material)
```